# How to migrate a site collection with custom Master Page from SharePoint 2010 to 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, migration, sharepoint-2013

I am migrating my SharePoint site to 2013. I have used database attached method. Now I'm stuck at this stage. [image: Image Description] I am clicking on Start Now but it doesn't upgrade because of errors related to my Site Definitions and Master Page. I tried to convert my Site Definitions and Master Pages in SharePoint 2013 but it didn't help much either. And I am getting this error while deploying master page.

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id '' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Here is what I did:

1. I converted all the Page Layouts to SharePoint 2013.
2. After that I converted my Master Page and added Page Layouts dll into the GAC.
3. I deployed Master Page using power shell and used Compatibility Mode set to 11.

   Install-SPSolution -Identity MasterPage.wsp -GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel {14,15}

Then activate the feature and upload required files.

In this way the master page deployed into the Hive 15. After all this I went to the upgrade screen and upgrade my site to SharePoint 2013. Site upgraded successfully but still their problems in the CSS Style which I have to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any Feature Id provided? Do you have custom solutions installed on the SP 2010 farm which are currently not installed on the Sp 2013 farm? Normally this error results from the fact that you have features (solutions) on the old farm but not installed in the new one.

Please also check the following MSDN step-by-step guide:

[Introduction to Upgrade in SharePoint Server 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2012/07/17/introduction-to-upgrade-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Comment: Yes there was but I installed them before mounting the content database.

Comment: Could you please check by the Feature Id if this Feature was successfully installed? Maybe per Powershell -> http://www.randomizzzer.com/2012/03/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-sharepoint-feature-from-its-guid/ -> to ensure that the feature with this id is really installed